# how should i add a picture to my css code(i guess it needs borders)

Tags: html, css

Ive been learning html and css myself and i want to add an image and a text which moves when pages moves
Heres what i did

```
p1{
    color: black;
    font-family: courier; }
#p2{
    color:black;
    font-family:courier; } .a{
    color:yellow;
    font-family:courier;
    font-size: 30px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 10px auto ;
    margin-right: 200px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    border: 10px groove lightgreen; } body{
    background-color: cyan; } img{ margin-left:200px; }
```

and here's html code

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'kol.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id = p1>
        this is paragraph.

        </p>
        <p id = p2>
        paragraph2
        </p>
        <p class = 'a'>
        this is cool
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your post is "cut", could you reedit it and add some context?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question **itself**, rather than simply linking to a website. The website may be malicious, blocked by filter systems, or removed later on. It would also be helpful to let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Just insert important parts of a code into the "code sample" section, we won't download your files.

Comment: <div>
<h4 class="d-inline-block">Flower</h4>
<img src="flower.jpg">
</div>